# How to make sequential task lists

Tags: tasks, task-list, sequential

I have a project where there are multiple tasks running in parallel, each with subtasks that must be completed in sequence before the whole task is complete.

Eg.

```
- Task 1
    - Subtask 1
    - Subtask 2
    - Subtask 3
```

In order for Task 1 to be complete, all subtasks must be complete. Subtask 1 must be completed before Subtask 2, which must also be completed before Subtask 3.

There would also be Task 2, with subtasks, being processed in parallel. So within Task 2 the subtasks need to be completed in order, but Task 2 on the whole *could* be completed before Task 1.

Is there an effective way to express/enforce this in Sharepoint?

Thanks in advance!